# change the mastership of my stream to be able to deliver to parent stream

Tags: stream, clearcase-ucm

I have the following error when I try to deliver from stream `B` to parent stream `A`:

```
cleartool: Warning: Trigger "dlvr_start_precondition" has refused to let deliver_start proceed.
cleartool: Error: A deliver_start preop trigger does not allow this operation.
cleartool: Error: Unable to do integration.
cleartool: Error: Unable to deliver stream "A"
```

Was indicated to change the mastership of my stream temporary to be able to deliver to parent stream. My stream is on a different server then the parent stream.

I see that can be done with:

```
multitool chmaster –stream [ –ove·rride ] master-replica-selector stream-selector
```

In my case should be the following command?

```
multitool chmaster –stream A B
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`multitool chmaster man page`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_ref.doc/topics/mt_chmaster.htm?lang=en) does mention:

```
-str/eam [ -ove/rride ] master-replica-selector stream-selector ...
```

> Transfers mastership of the specified streams and their associated objects to the replica specified with `master-replica-selector`.
>   Specify `stream-selector` in the following form:

```
stream-selector
    [stream:]stream-name[@vob-selector]
```

> Use the `-override` option only if the `chmaster–stream` command fails.
>   With `-override`, `chmaster` attempts to transfer mastership of objects whose mastership was not transferred during the original invocation of the command.

In your case:

```
multitool chmaster –stream stream:A@\aPVob      siteB
multitool chmaster –stream stream:A@/vobs/aPVob siteB
```

with `siteB` being the site which masters the stream `B`.